# Save images as 8-bit grayscale in image_view extract from rosbag file

Tags: ros, extract-images, viso2-ros, image-view

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I use a launch-file in order to extract images from a stereo-camera (stereo/left & stereo/right).
Thereby I use the package "image_view" with the node "extract" to grab the images from my bagfile.

```
<launch>
   <arg name="path" default="/home/viki/bagfiles" />
   <arg name="bagfile" default="bagfile_stereo_raw.bag" />
   <arg name="folder_name" default="default_image_folder" />
   <arg name="format" default="png" />

   <param name="/use_sim_time" value="true" />

   <node name="rosbag" pkg="rosbag" type="play" 
      args="--clock -d 4 $(arg path)/$(arg bagfile)" />


   <node name="extract1" pkg="image_view"   type="extract_images" respawn="false" output="screen"                 cwd="ROS_HOME" >
   <remap from="image" to="/stereo/left/image_rect" />
   <param name="filename_format" value="/stereo_images/$(arg folder_name)/left/left_image%04i.$(arg                  format)"/>
   </node>

   <node name="extract2" pkg="image_view" type="extract_images"  respawn="false" output="screen"                  cwd="ROS_HOME" >
   <remap from="image" to="/stereo/left/image_rect" />
   <param name="filename_format" value="/stereo_images/$(arg folder_name)/right/right_image%04i.$(arg                  format)"/>
   </node>

</launch
```

I now receive all the desired images but they are 24-bit images.
Now my question is: How can I setup the launch-file in order to receive 8-bit (grayscale) images?
I cannot find any documentation regarding this. Also my question is how to obtain parameters from nodes like "extract" in ROS in general.
I found out that there is a parameter called "file_format" for "extract" in the ROS answer sites but how can I see all the different parameters there are for this node. (I am sure my question would resolve by acquiring this info).

Also one other question: I need to create the directories before saving the images (with the launch file) into them. Is there a way that the roslaunch file creates the desired directories by itself?

Thanks in advance!
Hector

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/188296/save-images-as-8-bit-grayscale-in-image_view-extract-from-rosbag-file/) by [mister_kay](https://answers.ros.org/users/18994/mister_kay/) on ROS Answers with karma: 238 on 2014-07-30

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-07-30**:
I believe your question about creating directories has been asked and answered elsewhere. ( http://answers.ros.org/question/188298/how-to-create-directories-in-a-ros-launch-file/ )

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-07-30**:
[image_proc](http://wiki.ros.org/image_proc) should be able to create mono images from color images, but it looks like you're already subscribing to a mono topic. Are the saved images color or monochrome when viewed?

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-07-30**:
There isn't any documentation of the extract_images node on the image_view wiki page. Perhaps you can write it once you've figured out all of the details?

**Comment by [mister_kay](https://answers.ros.org/users/18994/mister_kay/) on 2014-08-22**:
@ahendrix yes i can do that. unfortunately I couldn't find the site where ic an edit the documentaion for extract_images. can you give me a link for a tutorial how to create this docu?

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-08-22**:
The wiki page for image_view is http://wiki.ros.org/image_view , and you can sign up for an account [here](http://wiki.ros.org/action/newaccount/image_view?action=newaccount)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The hacky version is to edit the source code in the image_view package named extract_view.cpp [line 105]:

orginal:

```
image = cv_bridge::toCvShare(msg, "bgr8")->image;
```

edited:

```
image = cv_bridge::toCvShare(msg, "mono8")->image;
```

This way only 8bit grayscale images are extracted. (that was on of the things I wanted.)
Of course i had to "catkin_make" my catkin_workspace first before this works!

I think it would be a good idea to add a parameter which makes it possible for every user to
extract the images in her/his desired fileformat, e.g.

```
ros::NodeHandle nh("~");
string the_format;
const string default_format = "bgr8";

nh.param<std::string>("file_format", the_format, default_format);
....
image = cv_bridge::toCvShare(msg, the_format)->image;
```

I am not that good with GitHub, otherwise I would send a pull request to the creator of image_view.

---

Originally posted by [mister_kay](https://answers.ros.org/users/18994/mister_kay/) with karma: 238 on 2014-08-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [paulbovbel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3632/paulbovbel/) on 2014-08-22**:
Never too early/late to learn!

- open an issue in the repository
- fork the repo directly in the Github gui
- clone your fork, make/test your changes
- commit your changes, referencing the issue in the comment
- make a pull request through the Github gui to 'pull' your changes to the repo